# When should I use the embed tag over the dynamic/template tags?

Tags: templates, ee3, layout-variables

Since Layout templates are so handy (cutting the template into interchangeable header/sidebar/footer, etc), why should our use an embed tag? Any ideas on when you should not use an embed tag over a layout tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple difference is that you can use only 1 [layout template](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/layouts.html) to do what takes at least 2 [embeds](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/embedding.html) to be done: header and footer code sections. Every template parsing you save counts.

You can use embeds for several things:

- to nest the same module inside itself or modules which have conflicting variables inside each other, because this can cause serious conflicts on the same template. Like a `exp:channel:entries` tag inside another one or a `exp:comment:entries` inside a `exp:channel:entries`;
- to have a different template cache time on an embed from the template it's loaded;
- to have similar templates loading at different URLs, if you are too scared of routes. Something like `/cars` and `/boats` loading the same template;